# Multiplicativity of maximum norm

Tags: continuity, normed-spaces

Let $f\in C([a,b], \mathbb{K})$ and $\| f\|_\infty:= \max_{x\in[a,b]} |f(x)|$ be the maximum norm.
I was wondering if $\|f^n\|_\infty = (\|f\|_\infty)^n$ holds for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

By submultiplicativity of $\|.\|_\infty$, we clearly have $\|f^n\|_\infty \leq (\|f\|_\infty)^n$.
Is the reverse estimate also correct?

Comment: Yes, because you are then looking at just a single point $x$ and recover arithmetic properties of $\mathbb{K}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct, because $t \mapsto t^n$ is increasing on $[0, \infty)$.

For all $x \in [a,b]$ is
$$
|f(x)^n| = |f(x)|^n \le (\Vert f \Vert_\infty)^n
$$
with *equality* for the $x$ where the continuous function $|f|$ attains its maximum on $[a, b]$. It follows that $\Vert f^n \Vert = (\Vert f \Vert_\infty)^n$.

By the same argument is
$$
 \Vert h \circ f \Vert_\infty = h(\Vert f \Vert_\infty)
$$
if the function $h: \Bbb K \to \Bbb R$ is increasing on $[0, \infty)$ and satisfies $h(|t|) = |h(t)|$ for all $t$.

Comment: Am I correct that the statement is not true for a continous function that is given on an unbounded intervall?

Comment: @physicist23: The function may have a maximum on an unbounded interval. But if you replace the maximum by the supremum (which can be $\infty$) then the statement is still true.